# Armature go limp like noodle, how?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I want to have a character lift some really heavy weights then his strenght goes out and he collapses like a house of cards.

I know how to make the weights fall down in a collision, but how do I make the armature / object suddenly fall down like its made out of noodles? Is there a modifier or state for that so I don't have to animate the complex chaos of a limp fall?

Comment: You sir, are looking for a ragdoll animation! [https://youtu.be/HryXEpIz-cg](https://youtu.be/HryXEpIz-cg) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the skin into a [softbody](https://youtu.be/wJFE2pb0Ri4?t=1m7s) and make a new armature made out of mesh bones and apply rigid body constraints/joints .

But physics simulations cant effect regular armature bones.

But I think its a good idea, you should pitch that idea on [rightclickselect](https://rightclickselect.com/p/)